# php: Not able to add two times(working hours) in a year

Tags: php

I have to Add working hours in a year working hours are  given below how to add them

```
$time1 = 411:20 ;
$time2 = 107:15 ;
```

`strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2);`//not works

```
$timestamp = strtotime($time1." +".$time2);
$endTime = date("H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $endTime;
```

how to add them in terms of time i have tried various solutions but nothing works

please help

Comment: What are the "various solutions" you have tried? Please edit your post to add them.

Comment: Can it be in 000:00:00 format too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small utility function to sum your times:

This returns in `xx:xx:xx` format.

```
<?php
function add_time(array $times) {
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time)
    {
        list($hour,$minute,$second) = array_pad(explode(':', $time),3,null);
        $seconds += $hour*3600;
        $seconds += $minute*60;
        $seconds += $second;
    }
    $hours    = floor($seconds/3600);
    $seconds -= $hours*3600;
    $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
    $seconds -= $minutes*60;

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}


$time1 = "411:20";
$time2 = "107:10";

echo add_time(array($time1, $time2));
```

**Result:**

```
518:30:00
```

Comment: great but i have to use this inside foreach loop and it was giving error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_time() (previously declared

Comment: declare the function outside the for loop and only use function_call inside the loop

Comment: can you please tell how to add complete total of all the time comming like 
559:00 , 574:15 , 508:10 ,554:45 and so on it is possible to add them all

Comment: `echo add_time($array_variable_here)` if all your values are in array

Comment: is it possible to outside foreach loop

Comment: declare a variable inside foreach and reuse it outside

Answer (score 0):

Create array for time ie:

```
$timearray=array("411:20","107:15");
$tot=AddTime($time);
echo $tot;
```

AddTime function will look like this:

```
public function AddTime($times) {
    $minutes=0;
// loop throught all the times
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute;
    }
    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;
 // returns the time already formatted
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Your Output will be:

```
518:35
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This solution

```
  $time1 = "411:20";
    $time2 = "107:15";

    $decimalHours = decimalHours($time1,$time2);

    function decimalHours($time1,$time2)
    {
        $hms = explode(":", $time1);
        $hms2 = explode(":", $time2);
      $t1 = ($hms[0] + ($hms[1]/60));
      $t2 = ($hms2[0] + ($hms2[1]/60));
        return ($t1 + $t2) ;
    }

echo $decimalHours;
```